# Jetpack compose button with elevation and disable state weird behaviour

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I created custom button and when I apply elevation with disable state it has because of shadow some small box in middle and it looks like this. Here is also my code:

```
@Composable
fun PrimaryButton(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = false,
    text: String,
    onClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    Button(
        onClick = onClick,
        Modifier
            .height(44.dp)
            .shadow(
                elevation = 4.dp,
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(22.dp),
            )
            .then(modifier),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            backgroundColor = Style.colors.buttonPrimary,
            disabledBackgroundColor = Style.colors.buttonPrimary.copy(0.4f),
        ),
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(22.dp),
        enabled = enabled,
    ) {
        Text(
            text = text,
            style = Style.typography.phoenixTitle,
            color = Color.White
        )
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is `Style` here?

Comment: this is how shadow drawn underneath the view, I don't think there's anything you can do. What you can do is to pass opaque color to disabledBackgroundColor, with alpha = 1f

Answer (score 2):

```
fun ButtonSelectedCount(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    text: String,
    enable: Boolean,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Surface(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp),
        modifier = modifier,
        elevation = if (enable) 9.dp else 0.dp
    ) {
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(color = if (enable) Color.Red else Color.Red.copy(alpha = 0.1f))
                .clickable(enable) {
                    onClick()
                }
                .wrapContentHeight(),
            text = text,
            style = Typography.button.copy(color = Color.White),
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}
```

I Think, This is what you are looking for. Wish you early success

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `disabledElevation` parameter of the button `elevation` parameter.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun DisabledButtonWithElevation() {
    Button(
        enabled = false,
        colors = ButtonDefaults.outlinedButtonColors(
            containerColor = Color.White,
            contentColor = Color.Black,
            disabledContainerColor = Color.White,
        ),
        elevation = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(
            defaultElevation = 2.dp,
            pressedElevation = 2.dp,
            disabledElevation = 2.dp,
        ), onClick = {}) {
        Text("Click Me")
    }
}
```

[image]